# cpu_percent(interval=None) always returns 0 regardless of interval value PYTHON

Tags: python, psutil

The code always returns 0.0 values, regardless of interval values.

```
import psutil
p = psutil.Process()
print p.cpu_percent(interval=1)
print p.cpu_percent(interval=None)
```

Comment: Uhm I can reproduce it. It may be a bug in newer versions of `psutil`. (I've used other versions of the library and it always worked fine). Note that I could obtain non-zero values starting different threads in the current process.

Comment: Have you tried it with `psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)` like documented at https://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation#CPU? And I think when using the Process class you have to specify a PID (like `p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())`).

Comment: @ChristianBerendt: I read the documentation from the very same link and specified several PID's (valid and running), but I always got 0.0

Comment: >>> import psutil>>> p = psutil.Process()
>>> p.cpu_percent(interval=1)
0.0
>>> p.cpu_percent(interval=None)
0.0
>>>

Answer (score 10):

This behaviour is [documented](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.cpu_percent):

> When interval is `0.0` or `None` compares process times to system CPU times elapsed since last call, returning immediately. That means the first time this is called it will return a meaningless `0.0` value which you are supposed to ignore. In this case is recommended for accuracy that this function be called a second time with at least `0.1` seconds between calls.

There is also a warning against using `interval=None` for a single call:

> **Warning:** the first time this function is called with *interval* = `0.0` or `None` it will return a meaningless `0.0` value which you are supposed to ignore.

If using `interval=None`, make sure to call `.cpu_percent` compared to a prior call.

```
p = psutil.Process(pid=pid)
p.cpu_percent(interval=None)
for i in range(100):
    usage = p.cpu_percent(interval=None)
    # do other things
```

instead of:

```
for i in range(100):
    p = psutil.Process(pid=pid)
    p.cpu_percent(interval=None)
    # do other things
```

Comment: it still returns 0.0

Answer (score 5):

The cpu of a Process object is mutable. I have done some tests for you.

```
for i in range(10):
    p = psutil.Process(3301)
    print p.cpu_percent(interval=0.1)
```

result:

`9.9 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 9.9 0.0 9.9 0.0 0.0`

So if you want to get the CPU percent of a Process object, you could take the average in certain time.

```
test_list = []
for i in range(10):
    p = psutil.Process(6601)
    p_cpu = p.cpu_percent(interval=0.1)
    test_list.append(p_cpu)
print float(sum(test_list))/len(test_list)
```

result:

`1.98`

[image: More info in picture]

Answer (score 4):

- **Monitor the current process**, i.e., `p = psutil.Process()` or `p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())`

  1. with interval value great than 0, `p.cpu_percent()` will always render you 0.0, because it will block your current process. During the blocking period, the cpu percent is **actually** 0.0;
  2. with interval value being 0.0 or None, calling another `p.cpu_percent()` immediately after `p.cpu_percent()` will also return 0.0. The period between that two calls is too short for `psutil` to monitor correctly. So **make sure at least 0.1 sec elapsed between two calls**.
- **Monitor some other process**, i.e., `p = psutil.Process(other_pid)`

  1. interval value great than 0 will probably get you the expected value;
  2. interval value being 0.0 or None, you still should not call the `cpu_percent()` function too shortly after another, reason the same as above.

---

**Another Note:**

**`p = psutil.Process()` should be called just once and reuse `p` afterwards**, rather than call it every time before you call `p.cpu_percent()`; otherwise you are actually calling `cpu_percent()` function the first time whenever you call `p.cpu_percent()`, with unexpected return value 0.0.

Answer (score 2):

From my own code that works:

```
cpu = psutil.cpu_times_percent(interval=0.4, percpu=False)
```

Comment: But I need to find the CPU percent of a Process object