# how to get all process information in linux?

Tags: python, linux, top-command

I want to get all process information in a linux server. 
`PID, USER, CPU% , COMMAND ...`
Exactly, I want to get these information in a python script. I tried 
`a,b = commands.getstatusoutput('top -n 1')`
This gave me about 20 rows of results ordered by CPU%, but I want more, about 40 or 50 rows of results.

### How should I do?

I use psutil as follow, for each proc, it need to wait 1 second. How can I get cpu_percent like top command quickly.

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'username', 'cpu_percent', 'name'])
        pinfo['cpu_percent'] = proc.cpu_percent(interval=1)
        if pinfo['cpu_percent'] > 0:
            print(pinfo)
        except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            pass
```

Comment: 1st read the manual of top

Comment: Read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Comment: Actually I read the manual of top, but I misunderstood the function of "top -b".  nexus66 gives me the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you using [psutil library](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/) like what **zenlc2000** said in his comment.
However, you can use the output of top's command.

You have also to take a look at [top command's manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/top) or simply writing `man top` in your terminal.

I give you an example of using top command's output within Python3 (or Python2):

Let's suppose i want to know top command's output for **gedit**:

```
$ top -b n 1 | grep gedit
```

**Output:**

```
8381 nexus   20   0  565928  43696  30268 S   0,0  1,1   0:06.03 gedit
```

In order to understand the output i'll write it with the keys:

```
 PID  UTIL     PR    NI    VIRT     RES    SHR   S  %Cpu %MEM TEMPS+   COM.
 8381 nexus    20    0     565928   43696  30268 S  0,0  1,1  0:06:03  gedit
```

Now, we'll filer the output with **awk**:

```
$ echo -n "%CPU: " && top -b n 1 | grep gedit | awk '{print $9}'
```

**Output:**

```
%CPU: 0,0
```

Or simply:

```
$ top -b n 1 | grep gedit | awk '{print $9}'
```

**Output:**

```
0,0
```

Using Python3 (or any version you want) in your terminal:

```
$ python3
>>> import subprocess
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen("top -b n 1 | grep gedit | awk '{print $9}'", shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p = proc.communicate()
>>> p[0].decode("utf8").replace("\n","")
```

**Output:**

```
0,0
```

And here you go! You got gedit process percentage using Python3 and the output of top command.

You can repeat this process to get all the informations you want from top's output.

Comment: Thank you, "-b" is what I need.  I read the manual of top before, but I misunderstood the function of "-b".

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling an external process like top, build the info yourself.  Check out the [psutil library](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/). It should give you all the data you need.

Comment: It is easy to use, but  when I use <code>pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'username', 'cpu_percent', 'name'])</code>, cpu_percent returns 0.0

Comment: Are you sure the cpu percent was greater than 0?

Comment: I test for all running proc, so at least one proc is greater than 0.

Comment: What interval value are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367424/cpu-percentinterval-none-always-returns-0-regardless-of-interval-value-python

Comment: The default value is None, so it returns 0.   But when I set interval value to 1, the program is too slow. How could I speed up it.

Comment: Hmmm... without seeing your code or knowing why you need it faster, I can only give generalities. Read less data, use Numpy for storing data, use pypy, do jit compiling with numba (library from Continuum Analytics), etc.